# Best practices for dynamically generating JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to add dynamic content to JavaScript, especially configuration settings?

A couple possibilities are:

1. Place the content in a dynamically generated file (e.g., JSP, PHP, etc.) rather than a JavaScript file, perhaps using an object literal.
2. Request the content from the server via ajax as JSON.

Comment: *"Use a JavaScript literal."* Huh?

Comment: It depends. I prefer static libraries and then fetch dynamic data using AJAX when necessary. Why exactly would you need dynamic JavaScript files?

Comment: I have several reasons to use dynamically generated JavaScript.  One is to set the options for a jQuery plug-in (jqGrid specifically), which usually change each time a page is viewed. Another reason is to accommodate internationalization messages.

Comment: @T.J. JavaScript literal: http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php

Comment: @Jack: Okay, so that's a dynamically-generated thing then, exactly like option #1. You can see how one would be confused.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest to put as much JavaScript as possible in a static resource (so the browser can cache that) and just generate the smallest possible dynamic part. Often that's just a few variable assignments.

This approach saves network bandwidth, it makes the code generation more robust, and you can test the static JavaScript as usual.

Answer (score 2):

We **do not** generate dynamic JavaScript.

We **do** generate dynamic HTML

Then use **progressive enhancement** to enhance the HTML with JavaScript. If you want to store data, store it in HTML5 `data-` attributes on *relevant* HTML elements.

Alternatively you write a Web Service and query it with **AJAX** to get dynamic data.